# Line break and add in the second line

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe that is incorporated in the DT table. But the sentences are long. So can we break the sentences and put in the second line

This is the dataframe with 2 rows

```
df
COlA 
Sentence is too long to be written here
Sentence is too long to be written here
```

Expected output

```
df
COlA 
Sentence is too long 
-to be written here
Sentence is too long 
-to be written here
```

Comment: I assume this is a DT in shiny question, right?

Comment: Yeah :) .......

Comment: insert a `\n`?  Then I think you have to `escape = F` in the data.table options.

Comment: where to insert ````\n```` ?

Comment: here: `Sentence is too long\nto be written here` When this is not working use `<br/>` intstead of `\n`. I can't test it right now.

Comment: or do you want a new own row ?

Comment: No. Replace that we new (inserting \n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep all automatically set the same widths for the whole column you can use

```
stringr::str_wrap("Sentence is too long to be written here", width = 20)
```

To make the changes visible in you shiny application you would the also need to add the following lines somewhere in you ui code

```
tags$style(
          "td{white-space:pre;"
        )
```